# Pasting range in next empty cell causes run-time error 424: 'Object Required'

Tags: excel, vba

I copied a range from one worksheet into the next empty row in another worksheet through below code. But this raise an exception

> run-time error 424; 'Object Required'.

```
Sub copy()
Dim lr1 As Long
lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr1).copy
End Sub

Sub paste()
Dim lr2 As Long
lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial.xlValues
End Sub
```

The error occurs when I run the "Paste" macro. I want to reiterate that the copied range does get pasted in the next empty cell, however this error message get displayed.

Which part of the "Paste" macro triggers this message?

Comment: `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

Comment: Why two different subs?

Answer (score 1):

When pasting just values, skip the clipboard:

```
Sub copy()
    Dim lr1 As Long
    lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr1)

    Dim lr2 As Long
    lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an application-defined/object-defined error on my side

Comment: @giveitaway my bad.  Forgot the `.Count` on the rows.

Comment: Hi Scott, what does ```Resize(rng.Rows.Count)``` do?

Comment: When assigning values directly the source range and target range need to be the same size.  `Resize(rng.Rows.Count)` makes the ranges the same size starting with `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2).Offset(1, 0)` as the first cell and going down.

Answer (score 0):

A single sub and modification:

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr1).copy
lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code as per BigBen's correction to the following;

```
Sub copy()
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr1).copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

@Scott Craner: I had two subs as I'm new to vba and it's a way to break down the code so that I can understand what the code is supposed to do, but I guess that can be done with comments.

Comment: Just a teaching note.  As you get into loops, avoiding the clipboard will save a lot of time.  If one is only interested in the values then simply assigning the values is quicker than copy/paste.  In this instance the difference is negligible, but compound that in a loop and it becomes noticeable.